# When ordering answers on vote count, the question scores are displayed on Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

There were lots of *UI* changes on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) in the last days.

But I just noticed some functionality change: when ordering (in the *Activity* tab) the answers on votes, the answers are properly ordered, but the (answer's) question score is displayed (instead of answer's):

[image: Img00]

For example, in the image above, my first answer has a score of **267**, not **6445** (at the time of this post).

From my point of view, this is a bug.

As a note, the behavior is not encountered on [Super User](https://superuser.com).